# Why does this API return unexpected content?

Tags: python, rest, curl, python-requests

### **What I am trying to do**

I am trying to replicate an API call from this site called [whoscored](https://www.whoscored.com/Regions/252/Tournaments/2/Seasons/5826/England-Premier-League)

**The API call**: I want to get the lists (marked green in the screenshot attached below) returned when I press the little triangle button (marked orange) to go to another date. What I want are actually the match_ids - the first numbers in these response lists (959734, 959847,...).

[image]

**My issue**: However when I try this on Python or cURL, I keep getting a 404 page HTML or an empty list in both Python and cURL.

**Code**: My code for the cURL is what I got from `copy as curl`. I then used [this site](http://curl.trillworks.com) to convert the cURL to Python Requests.

```
import requests

headers = {
    'sec-fetch-mode': 'cors',
    'cookie': 'visid_incap_774904=3kEvtXT6Tj6Xzoe/RUIgJu72zlwAAAAAQUIPAAAAAAC3g3aCi3Pnbw4WzyEOL6+j; incap_ses_438_774904=Eh88UGT+mSfTIkNTBBkUBr9mW10AAAAATaHYUuDom6e9m7mfUm13Sw==; _cmpQcif3pcsupported=1; googlepersonalization=OlkgPGOlkgPGgA; eupubconsent=BOlkgPGOlkgPGAKAYAENAAAA6AAAAA',
    'accept-encoding': 'gzip, deflate, br',
    'accept-language': 'en-US,en;q=0.9',
    'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_14_5) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/76.0.3809.100 Safari/537.36',
    'accept': 'text/plain, */*; q=0.01',
    'referer': 'https://whoscored.com/Regions/252/Tournaments/2/Seasons/5826/England-Premier-League',
    'model-last-mode': 'gYCkNzrx6WdIiTy4IlIqU5+yR+YgSH7OmhZfJbHMexA=',
    'authority': 'http://whoscored.com',
    'x-requested-with': 'XMLHttpRequest',
    'sec-fetch-site': 'same-origin',
}

params = (
    ('d', '2016W19'),
    ('isAggregate', 'false'),
)

response = requests.get('https://whoscored.com/tournamentsfeed/12496/Fixtures/', headers=headers, params=params)

#NB. Original query string below. It seems impossible to parse and
#reproduce query strings 100% accurately so the one below is given
#in case the reproduced version is not "correct".
# response = requests.get('https://whoscored.com/tournamentsfeed/12496/Fixtures/?d=2016W19&isAggregate=false', headers=headers)

print(response.text)
```

**Additional issues**: I've talked this over with another person who was getting the desired lists initially. But after a few tries, even he started getting back HTML content.

I think it's an Incapsula incident. The server probably knows the request is being generated by a script and hence, it's blocking us.

Would there be any fix to this issue? I've heard of using TOR to change IP addresses for every request but I'm not familiar with that at all (and neither do I know if that will work).

Comment: Erm, why did the question get downvoted?

Comment: Not sure, but I upvoted it for you..

Comment: Yes, use some delay and use some proxies. I am too getting the same thing even tried with session and all headers

Comment: @Vim Could you provide some example because I haven't done this before? Which library should I be looking at, for example?